# How can I log new activity/update a field when contact appears in report?

Tags: reporting, contact, field-update, activities

I'm in higher education, and we use our org to manage the admissions process. Emails, reporting, all of that is a breeze, but we also send out some essential information by way of our postal fulfillment center. We communicate with the fulfillment center by sending reports so that they know what to send to whom. That's also going swimmingly.

*The problem is that for customer service reasons, I need to have other users be able to see a list of reports that contained the contact they are viewing, and the date that they were included in the report.*

**How can I log a new activity or update a field on the contact object when a contact appears in a report?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a record show up in a report it means that it has satisfied the filter conditions / parameters which is defined for that particular report.

To address you problem you need to create workflow rule. Workflow rule is a way to automate some actions like sending an email, create a new task, updating a field etc when a particular record is inserted / updated.

Creating workflow in salesforce is very easy, you can check out the link [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm) to understand how to configure the workflow rule and associate a proper workflow actions.